# Tricking a Usercontrol to allow "." namespaces

Tags: c#, wpf, controls

I have a 3rd party control (Visifire) which has a namespace that uses the "." format. This works fine in a WPF application, but not in a UserControl as it generates a "can't find assembly" if you try to include the namespace. This means I have to use code to add the control, set up the bindings, etc, etc, which is quite annoying as I would prefer to use XAML.
My thought was to trick the UserControl using the following:

```
namespace MyControl
{
  public class MyChart : Visifire.Charts.Chart
  {
     public MyChart () : base() {}
  }

  public partial Chart : UserControl
  {
    // All the control stuff goes here
  }
}
```

Then, in XAML, I would use:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyControl"

<Grid>
    <local:MyChart>
    </local:MyChart>
</Grid>
```

This doesn't seem to work, as it generates an exception.
Anybody have any tips on how I could get around this? THanks much!

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
<Grid xmlns:charts="clr-namespace:Visifire.Charts;assembly=Visifire">
    <charts:Chart>...</charts:Chart>
</Grid>
```

To import a fully-qualified namespace, does that not work for you?